# Escolha de campos em modal mediante valor de variável em php

Tags: php, javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um modal que abre os dados de clientes e tenho clientes cpf e cnpj, gostaria de mostrar os dados de acordo com o valor da variável $razao_social, se essa variável conter algum dado, então o modal mostra o conteúdo do cliente que possui um cnpj, do contrário mostra os dados do cliente que é cpf, pois, um cliente que não possua dados cnpj é um cliente que tem cpf e vice versa.
Como trata-se de um modal e ele abre numa lista com vários clientes preciso fazer esse tratamento com javascript, porém, não tenho afinidade com a linguagem. 
Fiz da forma que sei com php, e logo dessa forma a modificação fica presente para todos que aparecem na lista e não é o certo, quero que cada modal tenha sua própria busca individual filtrando se é cnpj ou cpf, ou seja, tenho que empregar o javascript.
Segue o exemplo em php:

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<!--Alinhamento de Campos-->
<input id="id_cadastro" type="hidden" class="form-contratol" name="id_cadastro">
<!--Primeira Coluna-->
<div class='row' align = left>
 <!--Alinhamento de Campos Primeira Coluna-->
 <div class='col-sm-6'>
  
  
  <?php
   $razao_social = "TESTE LTDA";
   if ($razao_social != ''){
    echo "<!--Campo Razão Social-->
    <label for='razao_social' class='control-label' >
    <br>Razão Social:<br></label>
    <div class='input-group'>
    <div class='input-group-addon'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' id='basic-addon-razao_social'></span>
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='razao_social' id='id_razao_social' class='form-control'                      required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: José Emanoel'><br>
    </div>
    <!--Fim Campo Razão Social--> 
    
    <!--Campo NOME_FANTASIA-->
    <label for='razao_social' class='control-label' >
    <br>Nome Fantasia:<br></label>
    <div class='input-group'>
    <div class='input-group-addon'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' id='basic-addon-razao_social'></span>
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='razao_social' id='id_razao_social' class='form-control' required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: José Emanoel' onkeyup='limite_nome_fantasia(this)'><br>
    <script>
    function limite_cliente(obj) {
    obj.value = obj.value.substring(0,70);
    }
    </script>
    </div>
    <!--Fim Campo NOME_FANTASIA-->
    
    <!--Campo CNPJ-->
    <label for='cnpj' class='control-label' >
    <br>CNPJ:<br></label>
    <div class='input-group col-lg-8'>
    <div class='input-group-addon'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' id='basic-addon-cnpj'></span>
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='cnpj' id='id_cnpj' class='form-control cnpj' maxlength='30' required autofocus placeholder='Apenas Números'><br>
    </div>
    <!--Fim Campo CNPJ-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>";
   }else{
    echo "<!--Campo CPF-->
    <label for='cpf' class='control-label' >
    <br>CPF:<br></label>
    <div class='input-group'>
    <div class='input-group-addon'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' id='basic-addon-cpf'></span>
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='cpf' id='id_cpf' class='form-control'                      required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: José Emanoel'><br>
    </div>
    <!--Fim Campo CPF--> 
    
    <!--Campo NOME-->
    <label for='nome' class='control-label' >
    <br>Nome:<br></label>
    <div class='input-group'>
    <div class='input-group-addon'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' id='basic-addon-nome'></span>
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='nome' id='id_nome' class='form-control' required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: José Emanoel'><br>
    </div>
    <!--Fim Campo NOME-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>";
    
   ?>
```

Comment: detalha mais isso ai amigo.

Comment: Vou editar a pegunta pra esclarecer melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Bom se entendi direito isso te ajuda...

usei o esse link para simular os dados que vem do teu php [link](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpRNIadlua?indent=2)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVeVjPcxBu?indent=2",
    context: document.body
  }).complete(function(data) {
    var dados = data.responseJSON;
     dados.forEach(function(dado, index) {
      var tr = document.createElement("tr");
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      if(dado.razaoSocial != ""){
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dado.razaoSocial));
      } else { 
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dado.cpf));
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dado.endereco));
      tr.appendChild(td);
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dado.nome));
      tr.appendChild(td);
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dado.faturamento));
      tr.appendChild(td);
      var table = document.getElementById("tablePlayer");
      table.appendChild(tr);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>tabela de players</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Razao Social ou CPF</th>
                    <th scope="col">Endereco</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                    <th scope="col">Faturamento</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablePlayer" />
        </table>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Explicando o código, tenho uma tabela, que poderia ser um modal ou qualquer outra coisa... e ela é populada pelos dados que tem no seu servidor..

Tem um if verificando se tem razao social e se tiver ele faz algo se nao vc faz outra coisa:

```
if (dado.razaoSocial != "") {
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dado.razaoSocial));
} else {
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dado.cpf));
}
```